# How snap object to X, Y or Z-axis?

Tags: snapping, axis

I am a Blender n00b and have this beginners question that I can't find an answer for.

I'm following this course by testedpancake on YouTube to model a car. In part 7 of his tutorial he is extruding the hood of the car to the Y-axis: 
[Model a 3d Car | part 7 | hood vents and topology examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EYTh7dBBLA)

In my case I cannot get one point of the edge that I want to align with the Y-axis to snap to it. Please see the pictures below.

When I zoom in the vertice is not attached to the Y-axis

My question: how do I snap a vertice to the Y-axis?

Can somebody please help me out? Thank you!

EDIT: Here's the file: [Dodge Challenger car](http://[%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5475%22%20/%3E](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5475/))

Selecting the edge to move to Y-axis
[image: Selecting the edge to move to Y-axis]

Having 2 points snapped to the Y-axis, but not really!
[image: Having 2 points snapped to the Y-axis, but not really!]

When I zoom in, the vertice is not aligned with the green Y-axis at all!
[image: When I zoom in, the vertice is not aligned with the green Y-axis at all!]

Comment: hello bushok, perhaps share your file so that we can check it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: try activating clipping in the mirror modifier and pull the vertex all the way to the left and it should stuck to the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable *clipping* in the mirror modifier and then try again. If you now move your vertices to the left they should stop when they touch the other mirrored vertices.

Comment: Thank you very much Valentin, that was it! Just checking a box.. :)